# entity framework & web forms

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I have no experience with the entity framework and web forms... So far I've created the DB and the entity model in .net.

Now I have to create a form that inserts data into one of the tables of the DB. Is there a way to autogenerate the form using the entity model like in MVC?

EDIT:
Also, is it possible to reference the field names of the database (eg. ProductId, Name,...) so I don't have to hardcode them in the form?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to add [DetailView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w1w7t4.aspx) control + [EntityDataSource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/18/tutorial-entity-data-source-control.aspx) control and let the view autogenerate fields for you but it will make them all editable.

Comment: I just had a look at this. it works, but is there a way where you can position/style the form fields? DetailView doesn't seem to allow much control over this?

Comment: Only with CSS or ASP.NET themes.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Dynamic Data for ASP .NET. Check out the following;

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=232

Comment: looks interesting but it's a bit late for that as I'm already working with an existing site...

Comment: You can easily integrate dynamic data into an existing website: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2008/06/23/how-to-add-dynamic-data-to-an-existing-web-site.aspx